# SQL query is returning me twice the same data in datatable

Tags: php, sql

I have a datatable with multiple tables from SQL joining and i don't know why is returning me twice same data in datatable even on search in datatable, i have write at the end of SELECT the GROUP BY ID and is ok is stoping showing me twice the data but after this the search is not working any more, please se my code.

[image: Data showing twice]

PHP Code:

```
$request=$_REQUEST;
$col =array(
    0 => 'id',
    1 => 'parinte',
    2 => 'participant',
    3 => 'varsta',
    4 => 'email',
    5 => 'telefon',
    6 => 'plati',
    7 => 'status',
    8 => 'prin',
    9 => 'data',
    10 => 'operatii'
); 
                           $sql ="SELECT o.*, 
                           oi.pid,
                           oi.orderid,
                           oi.pquantity,
                           c.cid,
                           c.catname,
                           p.name, 
                           p.description,
                           p.catid,
                           u.firstname,
                           u.lastname,
                           u.mobile,
                           u.email,
                           usr.nume_participant,
                           usr.varsta_participant
                              FROM orders o,
                                   orderitems oi,
                                   products p,
                                   usersmeta u,
                                   category c,
                                   users usr
                             WHERE o.id    = oi.orderid
                               AND oi.pid  = p.id
                               AND o.uid   = u.uid
                               AND p.catid = c.cid
                               AND usr.id  = u.uid";
                             
$query=$db->query($sql);
$totalData=$db->numRows($query);
$totalFilter=$totalData;
//Search
                           $sql ="SELECT o.*, 
                           oi.pid,
                           oi.orderid,
                           oi.pquantity,
                           c.cid,
                           c.catname,
                           p.name, 
                           p.description,
                           p.catid,
                           u.firstname,
                           u.lastname,
                           u.mobile,
                           u.email,
                             usr.nume_participant,
                             usr.varsta_participant
                              FROM orders o,
                                   orderitems oi,
                                   products p,
                                   usersmeta u,
                                   category c,
                                   users usr
                             WHERE o.id    = oi.orderid
                               AND oi.pid  = p.id
                               AND o.uid   = u.uid
                               AND p.catid = c.cid
                               AND usr.id  = u.uid 
                               AND 1=1";

if(!empty($request['search']['value'])){
    $sql.=" AND (o.id Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR o.orderstatus Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR u.mobile Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR usr.email Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR u.lastname Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=$db->query($sql);
$totalData=$db->numRows($query);

//Order
$sql.=" ORDER BY ".$col[$request['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$request['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".
    $request['start']."  ,".$request['length']."";

$query=$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, it is a bit hard to understand the question.  A much simpler query might also increase the chance that someone would help.

Comment: The posted code doesn't output anything at any point so it's a bit hard to know what and how you actually return it to DataTables. It also helps if we know what the above code should do and why you're making multiple queries.

Comment: Ok guys u will update my code for better understanding

Comment: I will try, thanks for the tip